# Null Pointer Exception While deploying Spring Jax RS SERVICES Application with jasypt in Jboss

Tags: spring, hibernate, cxf, jboss7.x, jasypt

While deploying service on jboss-as-7.0.2.Final I am getting the following exception. While the same code is working properly when is run it from inside eclipse on jboss.

```
15:30:02,220 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/searchservice]] (MSC service thread 1-16) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
15:30:03,105 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/searchservice]] (MSC service thread 1-16) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.SimplePBEConfig.getPasswordCharArray(SimplePBEConfig.java:434) [jasypt-1.9.0.jar:]
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.resolveConfigurationPassword(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:740) [jasypt-1.9.0.jar:]
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:590) [jasypt-1.9.0.jar:]
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:553) [jasypt-1.9.0.jar:]
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:705) [jasypt-1.9.0.jar:]
    at org.jasypt.properties.PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.java:72) [jasypt-1.9.0.jar:]
    at org.jasypt.spring3.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.convertPropertyValue(EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:109) [jasypt-spring3-1.9.0.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertProperties(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:95) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:72) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:640) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:405) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [:1.7.0_09-icedtea]

15:30:03,159 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-16) Error listenerStart
15:30:03,159 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-16) Context [/searchservice] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Following is the application context file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <jaxrs:server id="srdhSearchService" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="searchServiceInterface" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
    <!-- 
    <bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:databaseResources.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
     -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.jasypt.spring3.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>databaseResources.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="commonDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${commonDataSourceDriver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${commonDataSourceUrl}" />
        <property name="username" value="${commonDataSourceUsername}" />
        <property name="password" value="${commonDataSourcePassword}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="2"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="400"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="300"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="10"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>

        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="5000"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>

        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="10000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="enrollmentDataSource1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${enrollmentDataSourceDriver1}" />
        <property name="url" value="${enrollmentDataSourceUrl1}" />
        <property name="username" value="${enrollmentDataSourceUsername1}" />
        <property name="password" value="${enrollmentDataSourcePassword1}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="2"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="400"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="300"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="10"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>

        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="5000"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>

        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="10000"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="enrollmentDataSource2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${enrollmentDataSourceDriver2}" />
        <property name="url" value="${enrollmentDataSourceUrl2}" />
        <property name="username" value="${enrollmentDataSourceUsername2}" />
        <property name="password" value="${enrollmentDataSourcePassword2}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="2"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="400"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="300"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="10"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>

        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="5000"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>

        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="10000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="seedingDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${seedingDataSourceDriver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${seedingDataSourceUrl}" />
        <property name="username" value="${seedingDataSourceUsername}" />
        <property name="password" value="${seedingDataSourcePassword}" />

        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="5000"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>

    </bean>


    <bean id="commonSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="commonDataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ManagedSessionContext</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${hibernate.defaultSchema.common}</prop>

            </props>

        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>auditWebServiceSearch.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>login.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>srdh_census_master_mapping.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="enrollmentSessionFactory1"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="enrollmentDataSource1" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ManagedSessionContext</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${hibernate.defaultSchema.enrollment1}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>enrollmentDetails.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>enrollmentphoto.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="enrollmentSessionFactory2"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="enrollmentDataSource2" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ManagedSessionContext</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${hibernate.defaultSchema.enrollment2}</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>enrollmentphoto.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>enrollmentDetails.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="seedingSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="seedingDataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ManagedSessionContext</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>seedingDictionary.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="searchServiceInterface"
        class="in.gov.uidai.srdh.portal.service.impl.SearchWebServiceImpl">
        <property name="searchServiceImpl" ref="searchService"></property>
        <property name="loginDAO" ref="loginDAO"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="searchService" class="in.gov.uidai.srdh.portal.service.impl.SearchServiceImpl"
        scope="prototype">
        <property name="searchDAO" ref="searchDAO" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="searchDAO" class="in.gov.uidai.srdh.portal.dao.impl.SearchDAOImpl"
        scope="prototype">
        <property name="dbController" ref="dbController" />
        <property name="commonSessionFactory" ref="commonSessionFactory" />
        <property name="seedingSessionFactory" ref="seedingSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginDAO" class="in.gov.uidai.srdh.portal.dao.impl.LoginDAOImpl"
        scope="prototype">
        <property name="commonSessionFactory" ref="commonSessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="dbController" class="in.gov.uidai.srdh.portal.common.util.DBController">
        <property name="enrollmentSessionFactory1" ref="enrollmentSessionFactory1" />
        <property name="enrollmentSessionFactory2" ref="enrollmentSessionFactory2" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration"
        class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
        <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
        <property name="passwordEnvName" value="SRDH_KEY" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
        <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Comment: Any chance we could see the code?

Comment: I am passing the encoded password through database.properties file. I have posted the application context file above